# Paring XML that is equal to a parsed field

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

Having played around with this I am wondering where I'm going wrong? I am parsing a XML file that returns lots of fields within the XML file and I want to return only the rows of the XML that are equal to or greater than a referenced field.

The 'occ' field is what I am trying to reference so I figured I needed to state it was a Integer using parseInt. The XML Parser looks for anything that is under the "fault' category and brings back that data, as stated I want to only show occurances (occ) greater than or equal to 5, within the normal scope of the XML there will 1's through to 10's for example.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
$(xml).find("fault").each(function () { 
            liv = $(this).attr("live");

            var partname = $(this).find("part").text();
            var defect = $(this).find("defect").text();
            var model = $(this).find("model").text();
            var location = $(this).find("location").text();
            var causal = $(this).find("causal").text();
            var occ = parseInt($(this).find("occ").text());

            var wkzero = $(this).find("wkzero").text();                  
            var wkone = $(this).find("wkone").text();
            var wktwo = $(this).find("wktwo").text();
            var wkthree = $(this).find("wkthree").text();
            var keyserial = $(this).find("keyserial").text();
```

I have tried changing the first line to be:

```
$(xml).find("occ:gt(4)").each(function () {
```

to no avail... Would someone be able to explain how to accomplish this please? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Trying to go about this the wrong way, sussed it out by adding this at the end with what I want to reference...:

```
if(occ>=(val)){
    Other code here...
}
```